View from the present on the past
Does it sound natural if I say in this writing style, meaning that some situation that happened in the past is being judged in the present, and the second sentence it's being judged in past.

View from the present on the past


View from the past on the present


I cannot understand your sentence after the comma all the way to the second comma. Today's View of the Past [title]

@Lambie changed it a little

Do you possibly mean that you wish to express the ideas of (1) the view of the past from the present and (2) the view of the present from the past?  And in what writing style do you mean?

Or said differently, (1) the past as viewed from the present and (2) the present as viewed from the past?

Views are not on but of.   Okay, we can speak of a view on a topic, but that means an opinion about the topic.

@PaulTanenbaum yeah, that's what I wanted, what if change "view" to "look"? Does it change point so much?

The nouns look and view are not synonyms. We can say things like Have [or Take] a look at this, which means examine this briefly. One also has look meaning appearance, style, or visual effect, as in That haircut is a popular look this year.
